# How to disable touch events in SwipeRefreshLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I use `SwipeRefreshLayout` by Google. and I have a few questions.

1. how to block for touch screen at the time when it is active `onRefresh()`?
2. how to make progress on the spinning center of the screen instead of the top, during the update?

   ```
   swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_status_info);
   swipeLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN);
   swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);


   @Override
   public void onRefresh() {
       clearTable(holidayTable);
       clearTable(cityayTable);
       setData();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to block some view (`blockedView`) from getting a touch event during the refresh you can consume that event in the OnTouchListener:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onRefresh() {
       clearTable(holidayTable);
       clearTable(cityayTable);
       setData();
       refreshing = true;
   }
   ...

   blockedView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           //consuming the touch
           if (refreshing) return true;
           //letting the touch propagate
           else return false;
       }
   });
   ```
2. set the desired `offset` in pixels using this method:

   ```
   swipeLayout.setProgressViewOffset(true, 0, offset);
   ```